# didSelectRowAtIndexPath return nil

Tags: swift

Почем возвращает nil? Я только учусь по этому не судите строго.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "Message"

    let cellMessage = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MessageTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...


    cellMessage.useravaImageView.image = UIImage(named: messageAvatarUser[indexPath.row])
    cellMessage.usermessageTextLabel.text = messageText[indexPath.row]
    cellMessage.timemessageTextLabel.text = timeMessageFrom[indexPath.row]
    cellMessage.usernameTextLabel.text = userNameFrom[indexPath.row]
    cellMessage.idTextLabelUser.text = idUserFrom[indexPath.row]

    return cellMessage
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCellMsg = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let selectMSG = selectedCellMsg!.textLabel!.text

    print(selectMSG)

}
```

Данные он выводи но при выборе элемента он возвращает nil как бы я не делал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что для `textLabel` Вы ничего не присвоили. К примеру, получить `usermessageTextLabel` непосредственно из `UITableView`:

```
let selectedCellMsg = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as! MessageTableViewCell
let selectMSG = selectedCellMsg.usermessageTextLabel!.text
```

А еще легче из источника:

```
let selectMSG = messageText[indexPath.row]
```